# make permutations of an array of numbers, then turn them into a single int

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, permutation

Basic idea: Given an array, find all the permutations of that array. Then, take each of those arrays and put it all together. Eg the array {6,5,3,4,1,2} gives you 653412. The permutations work, but I cannot get the integers.

```
int main ()
{

 int myints[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 int k;
 int dmartin=0;
 int powof10=1;

std::cout << "The 8! possible permutations with 8 elements:\n";

do {

    for(k=0; k<8; k++){
        std::cout << myints[k] << ' ';
        dmartin=myints[8-k-1]*powof10+dmartin;
        powof10=powof10*10;
    }
    cout << "\n"  << dmartin << "\n";



  } while ( std::next_permutation(myints,myints+8) );

  dmartin=0;
  return 0;
}
```

I also have some code that works when you just have one array, but in this case there are thousands. I though I needed to reset dmartin=0 at the end of each while loop so that it didn't keep adding to the previous answer, however when I tried that I got "0" for each of my answers. Without trying to reset, I get answers that seem random (and are negative).

Comment: who is this d.martin guy, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not resetting your two variables inside your loop, so they'll continue from the values they had during the previous iteration, which will just be wrong, and will quickly overflow, giving seemingly rubbish output. Try putting this at the beginning or the end of the do-while loop:

```
dmartin = 0;
powof10 = 1;
```

But you're really overcomplicating it a lot. It would be way simpler to just build the number from the most significant digit instead of the least significant one instead. This would eliminate the need for a `powof10` variable. This new for-loop would look like this:

```
for(k = 0; k < 8; k++){
    std::cout << myints[k] << ' ';
    dmartin = 10*dmartin + myints[k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work for long, since your integer will soon overflow.

That's probably what you are experiencing when you get negative numbers.

Using an integer to store the result does not seem the most appropriate choice to me. Why not use a string, for instance? That would save you the hassle of reinventing base10 conversion in 2014, and you could easily derive a number from the string when needed.

That won't solve the overflow problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

First point: the code to take a vector of digits and turn them into a single number should almost certainly be written as a function, not just code inside the loop.

Second point: you can use `std::string` like a container of `char`, and apply normal algorithms to it.

Seem to me, the lazy way would look like this:

```
std::string input="23456789";

do {
    std::cout<<std::stoi(input)<<"\n";
} while (std::next_permutation(input.begin(), input.end()));
```